# Use of DATETIME2 as a primary key for SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

I understand that under the covers SQL Server adds a 4 byte uniquifier to a DATETIME field used as INDEX in order to ensure that it is unique. This makes sense as the precision of DATETIME is the order of milliseconds so two inserts might share the same time. However, DATETIME2 has precision of 100 nano seconds so might that be enough to avoid duplicates even on the fastest servers? Does anyone know if SQL Server automatically adds the 4 byte uniquifier to DATETIME2?

Comment: The question is unclear. Adding 4 bytes happens when a table is a heap (doesn't have a clustered index). It has nothing to do with the type of the column.

Comment: The precision of the data type may go down to the level of 100 nanoseconds but e.g. `SYSDATETIME` doesn't guarantee what *accuracy* it provides. Other sources of `DATETIME2` values are also unlikely to have 100 nanosecond accuracy.

Comment: Vladimir: please can you provide a reference? Microsoft says "a uniqueifier is a 4-byte value used to make each key unique in a clustered index that allows duplicate key values" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luti/2018/02/16/uniqueifier-details-in-sql-server/

Comment: Damien: Good point about the accuracy, though I would hope that the same server would give different values for DATETIME2 on sequential INSERTS which is really the key. It's the precision of the value returned by whatever function the server uses to initialise the fields that's important; see comment below. If you had multiple servers then you might run into issues if their clocks weren't synchronised though there's little chance of server 1 inserting a record with exact the same time(+- 100 nanosec) as one already inserted by server 2 running with its clock forward of the server 1 clock.

Comment: Re: the uniqueifier - it's about the index definition, not about the data types involved. SQL Server doesn't go "oh, that's just a datetime, that won't be unique enough". It only cares about whether or not the clustered index has been declared `UNIQUE` (or implied by `PRIMARY KEY`)

Comment: you're right about uniqueifiers not being related to just the DATETIME data type - see link above. Thanks for pointing this out - Vladimir too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough at least on theory, but I have some legacy tables for logging changes where because of some client error, developer error or business error duplicate data is modified. It's something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] CHAR(1)
   ,[date] DATETIME2
   ,PRIMARY KEY([value], [date])
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value], [date])
VALUES ('x', SYSDATETIME());

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value], [date])
VALUES ('x', SYSDATETIME());
```

> (1 row affected) Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 11 Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#A1CDE66__9D260824E5008401'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.@DataSource'. The duplicate key value is
>   (x, 2018-10-23 08:22:24.7026304). The statement has been terminated.

So, depending on your code you can see similar situations, too. Note, you should use `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, not `GETUCDATE()` as the second returns `datetime`, not `datetime2`.

For some history table I found it normal to have as primary key the main table PK + change action (let's say char - (U)pdate, (D)elete, (I)nsert) + datetime2.

It depends also on what kind of searches you are going to have. For example, you can create a identity primary key and leave the SQL Server to handle it. At the same time you still can add your `DATETIME` column and created index on it in order to optimize searches per date.

Comment: Good point about the return value of GETUCDATE(). I should use SYSUTCDATETIME() instead as that returns datetime2 - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. I prefer UTC as when operating in the cloud you don't always know where your server is located. Thanks for raising the other points